# Header Issue In Report

Tags: reporting-services

I have a Report in which I have used 8 tables and there is header on top of page. Condition is that header should come for 5th table and repeat on every page of 5th table. If 5th table data comes in 4 pages than header should come for these 4 pages not for other pages.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the header on the report, put the header directly on the table, and then go to the table properties and select "Repeat header columns on each page".

Comment: thanks For Replying. But My issue is i can not put report header in table header cause table is in middle location after some tables and i need to show header on top of page.

Comment: So you want to display a header, when a table appears on the middle of a report, and that table can be broken in multiple pages? Can you upload an image with an example of what you want (with the multiple tables and pages and headers)

Answer (score 0):

At last find Solution:-
Place two rectangles, one inside the other.
Place your table inside the inner rectangle and set it to always be visible.
Set the inner rectangle's Page Break to Insert After Rectangle.
Set the outer rectangle's visibility to use your conditional expression.

The page break and the conditional visibility are now separated, and the inner rectangle's page break won't be processed if it is not visible, but it will if it is visible.

Its not showing effect in report viewer but in print and pdf it shows effects.